# e514: write error (file system full?) in linux' error even if you file system is not full?

Tags: filesystem, editing

I am trying to edit file `constraint_0_power_limit_uw` under `/sys/class/powercap/intel-rapl/intel-rapl:0`. When I try to edit it, I get

```
e514: write error (file system full?) in linux' error even if you file system is not full?
```

message even if my file system is not full. I attach the output of `df -h`.

How can I solve this problem?

Output of `df -h`:

[image]

Comment: Does the guide you are following say that you have to edit "the file"? /sys is not a real filesystem, but virtual one, exposing kernel objects.

Comment: No, it does not say. Do you mean I cannot edit file under /sys?

Comment: Exactly ,,, try googling "sysfs" and get some knowledge. Also you can google the 'file' you try to change (/sys/class/powercap/intel-rapl/intel-rapl:0) to find the right way to use it.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you. I checked output of df -h /sys. It will verify your answer.                                                                                                         
I get e514 error because it s virtual file system, so, it does not available space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't edit files in/sys because it is a virtual filesystem. `df -h /sys`shows that the device is "sysfs", not a physical one as /dev/sda1 or similar.

This virtual filesystem sysfs exposes kernel objects.